# How to remove Chrome OS Desktop Environment?

Tags: uninstall, desktop-environments, chromeos

I tried to [install Chrome OS Desktop Environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) but it didn't worked from some reason. I was prompted with a message saying that there is some error, so how can I remove the installed components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing installed components after incomplete installation of Chrome OS Desktop Environment can be done by using `Synaptic Package Manager`. Synaptic Package Manager can be installed from the Ubuntu Software Center.

After installing and opening the application in the search box, just type `ChromiumOS` and after it's listed in the field below where the full name of the package and it's version is specified, all you need is to right click on the name of the package.

Then, from the drop down menu, select the option "Mark for Complete Removal".

**After that select "Apply" and that's it.**